# Javascript libraries not loading from block class

Tags: theming, 8

I am working on porting module to drupal 8.

My block code is as follow

`public function build() {
  $delta= $this->getDerivativeId();
  $num           = str_replace('dexp_layerslider_block_', '', $delta);
  $sid = $this->configuration['dexp_layerslider_block_slide_'.$num];
  $block_id = $this->getDerivativeId();
  $slideshow = dexp_layerslider_load($sid);
  if (!$slideshow){
     return 'No slider selected';
  } 
  $content =   array(
      'id' => $sid,
      'slides' => $slideshow->slides,
      'settings' => $slideshow->settings
     );
   return array(
     '#theme' => 'dexp_layerslider_slides',
     '#items' => $content,
     '#attached' => array(
        'library' => array('dexp_layerslider/dexp.block'),
        ),
      );
}`
 
my yaml file: 

`dexp.slides:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css: {}
      css/admin.style.css: {}
      plugins/rs-plugin/css/settings.css: {}
  js:
    js/dexp.layerslider.js: {}
    js/layeroption.js: {}
    js/admin.layerslider.js: {}
    plugins/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js:  {}
    plugins/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js:  {}
 dexp.block:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      plugins/rs-plugin/css/settings.css: {}
      css/layerslider.css: {}
  js:
    plugins/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js:  {}
    plugins/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js:  {}
  dependencies:
    - core/drupal
    - core/jquery`

my theme function :

  `$themes['dexp_layerslider_slides'] = array(
    'template' => 'slides',
    'path' => $path . '/theme',
    'pattern' => 'layerslider__',
    'preprocess functions' => array(
      'template_preprocess',
      'dexp_layerslider_preprocess_slides'
    ),
    'variables' => array('items'=>null),
  );`

None of  javascript and css files are load , when i try to access items in twig template {{ items }} nothing gets printed , though if write random string in the my slide.html.twig file it get printed. where i could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a "dexp.slide" defined in your libraries.yml file. Only "dexp.block".

You're trying to attach a library that doesn't exist.

Comment: I was trying to post less code, i will update my question

Comment: its working now , i am using vi editor and i type the the above instead of copy and pasting and it started working!

Comment: I don't know what that means - other than the code in the post is still wrong. You are referencing a library to attach which doesn't match what is in your libraries.yml file, which is absolutely why none of those files are loading.

Comment: i do have dexp.block and file associated with dexp.block. some how it was not working and i retyped in vi editor it started working .

Comment: i updated my question.

Comment: Now it says dexp.slides and you're trying to attach dexp.slide. This is really confusing.

Comment: i corrected it  and its working as intended , earlier even with correct code and yaml some how libraries were not loading.